# Capitalizing Strings Input from User

Tags: c++, capitalization

I'm working on a problem where I have:

> the user input the number of names in a list and then input the names. Then I have to change the strings so that every name has the first character capitalized and the rest should be low letters.

If the names are input like this:

```
2 EliZAbetH paUL
```

The output should be like this:

```
Elizabeth Paul
```

This is what I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;
const int FYLKJASTAERD = 100;
int main()
{    
    int FjoldiOrd = 0;

    //get the number of students
    cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> FjoldiOrd;

    string Nofn[FYLKJASTAERD];

    //get student names
    for (int i=0; i<FjoldiOrd; i++)
    {
         cin >> Nofn[i];

         if (Nofn.length()>0)
         {
             Nofn[0] = std::toupper(Nofn[0]);
             for (size_t i = 1; i < Nofn.length(); i++)
             {
                  Nofn[i] = std::tolower(Nofn[i]);
             }
         }
    }
    cout << Nofn[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program is not compiling and it gives me this error:

```
request for member lenght in Nofn which is of non-class type 'std::string[100]
```

### Question:

Could please give me some pointers on what I am doing wrong?

### Note:

I've done a simpler version of this with just the input name and that works fine.

```
    string name;
    cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
    cin >> name;

    if( !name.empty() )
    {
        name[0] = std::toupper( name[0] );

        for( std::size_t i = 1 ; i < name.length() ; ++i )
            name[i] = std::tolower( name[i] );
    }
    cout << name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And?  is this not compiling?  does it compile but not work right?  If you are getting output what is it and what should it be?

Comment: Considering that this appears to be Icelandic, note that the argument to `std::toupper` from C needs to be a non-negative integer or `EOF`. So, cast it to `unsigned char`. And ditto for `std::tolower`.

Comment: Damn it, I forgot to put that in
the code is not compiling, it gives me this error: 
request for member lenght in Nofn which is of non-class type 'std::string[100]

Comment: Why not index that array.

Comment: @BMG The question should be edited/updated to include any/all relevant details (i.e., put the details your forgot in the question not the comments).

Comment: Maybe `if (Nofn.length()>0)` should be `if (Nofn[i].length()>0)`?

Comment: Please state the problem you have! Don't just add a comment. Edit your question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
    string Nofn[FYLKJASTAERD];
```

is an array of strings. So you need to add an [index] to get the string.

Consequently you can't ask for the length of Nofn.

You can however do

```
Nofn[i].length();
```

to get the length of the string at position i in the array of strings.

Further you use the variable name i twice. Which is pretty bad.

Maybe this would work better (but I have not tried it myself):

```
//get student names
for (int i=0; i<FjoldiOrd; i++)
{
     cin >> Nofn[i];

     if (Nofn[i].length()>0)
     {
         Nofn[i][0] = std::toupper(Nofn[i][0]);
         for (size_t j = 1; j < Nofn[i].length(); j++)
         {
              Nofn[i][j] = std::tolower(Nofn[i][j]);
         }
     }

}
cout << Nofn[i] << endl;
```

**however...**

I don't think your program does exactly what you want. cin to a string will stop at a space so you will get the name in trunks - not just one string with the name. To get the name including spaces use getline like this:

```
string name;
getline(cin, name);
```

This will complicate you upper/lower case code because you have to detect spaces. Maybe this could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

void fixString(string& s)
{
    bool doUpperCase = true;

    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ')
        {
            doUpperCase = true;
        }
        else
        {
             if (doUpperCase)
             {
                 s[i] = std::toupper(s[i]);
                 doUpperCase = false;
             }
             else
             {
                 s[i] = std::tolower(s[i]);
             }
         }
    }
}

const int FYLKJASTAERD = 100;
int main()
{    
    int FjoldiOrd = 0;

    //get the number of students
    cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> FjoldiOrd;
    while (cin.get() != '\n')
    {
        continue;
    }

    string Nofn[FYLKJASTAERD];

    //get student names
    for (int i=0; i<FjoldiOrd; i++)
    {
         getline(cin, Nofn[i]);
         fixString(Nofn[i]);
         cout << Nofn[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this helps alot :)